# actual size (1x1)px of icon does not match specified size (72x72)px | PWA Nuxtjs

Tags: nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps, manifest

I am trying to add PWA functionality to an existing Nuxt js website and i get this error in the console:

```
Error while trying to use the following icon from the Manifest: 
http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/static/icons/icon-144x144.png (Download error or resource isn't a 
valid image)
```

and this warning in the application tab Manifest:

```
actual size (1x1)px of icon http://localhost3000/_nuxt/static/icons/icon-72x72.png does not match specified size (72x72px)
actual size (1x1)px of icon http://localhost3000/_nuxt/static/icons/icon-96x96.png does not match specified size (96x96px)
actual size (1x1)px of icon http://localhost3000/_nuxt/static/icons/icon-128x128.png does not match specified size (128x128px)
```

and the same warnings for the rest of the icons.

manifest object content:

```
manifest: {
short_name: 'ProjectName',
name: 'Project Name',
start_url: '/en/',
theme_color: '#f0b54d',
display: 'standalone',
background_color: '#f0b54d',
orientation: 'portrait-primary',
icons: [
  {
    src: "./static/icons/icon-72x72.png",
    sizes: "72x72",
    type: "image/png"
  },
  {
    src: "./static/icons/icon-96x96.png",
    sizes: "96x96",
    type: "image/png"
  },
  {
    src: "./static/icons/icon-128x128.png",
    sizes: "128x128",
    type: "image/png"
  },
  {
    src: "./static/icons/icon-144x144.png",
    sizes: "144x144",
    type: "image/png"
  },
  {
    src: "./static/icons/icon-152x152.png",
    sizes: "152x152",
    type: "image/png"
  },
  {
    src: "./static/icons/icon-192x192.png",
    sizes: "192x192",
    type: "image/png"
  },
  {
    src: "./static/icons/icon-384x384.png",
    sizes: "384x384",
    type: "image/png"
  },
  {
    src: "./static/icons/icon-512x512.png",
    sizes: "512x512",
    type: "image/png"
  }
]
```

},

i tried to apply the Nuxt way of importing the icons by creating an icon object in `nuxt.config.js` file like this:

```
icon: {
   iconSrc: './static/icons/icon-512x512.png'
}
```

it does not recognize it at all and says that this project does not have an icon to show.

i notest another error in the console that says:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/static/icons/icon-144x144.png 404 (Not Found)
```

it show different icon with every refresh.

what i tried:
   - i tried different icons several times.
   - i tried to use vanilla js approach to write Manifest object.
   - i tried to use Nuxt PWA approach to import the icons.

screen shot of Manifest tab:
[image]

screen shot of network tab:
[image]

it says that icon-144x144.png is a GIF file!! which is weird.

so any help plz.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use an [absolute path](https://medium.com/@colinlmcdonald/absolute-vs-relative-paths-7ffd8e31d49c).

So instead of

`src: "./static/icons/icon-72x72.png",`

use

`src: "/static/icons/icon-72x72.png",`.

And make sure your `.png` icons are located in `projectRoot/static/icons`.
You can check if the icons exist at http://localhost:3000/icons/icon-144x144.png

Answer (score 1):

remove static from your path
should be
/icons/icon-512x512.png